# Does brute-force time depend on the length of a password only?

Tags: passwords, brute-force

If a password is +30 characters long but contains words from the dictionary, is it less secure than a 10-character password that is !@#$#%$^%$, for example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is faster - brute-forcing, or using a dictionary attack that contains all possible permutations?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152986/which-is-faster-brute-forcing-or-using-a-dictionary-attack-that-contains-all)

Comment: What do you mean by “contains words from the dictionary”?  “to-be-or-not-to-be,that-is-the-question”?  “righteous-equine-generator-paper-clip”?  “dad!&halt@^squander)$bridged%#situated”? “dAd!&haLt@^sQuaNder)$bRidGed%#siTuaTed”?

Comment: @Sup Go: Please tell us more dettails details what exactly you meant by password that "contains words from the dictionary" and what exactly you meant by "10-character password". Have you meant *any* characters* Have you meant that 10-character password consists of 5 different characters only?

Answer (score 20):

Length is certainly a factor, but you've hit on an underlying fact that most people miss: **even a 30 char password is weak if it is guessable**.

The concept that is important is "entropy". It's not just length or even the types of characters used, but **how the password is chosen**. The randomness, the character types used, and the length all contribute to password strength.

But if *everyone* uses the password: `Look at me!! I'm a really long password!!` (that's 41 characters), then it's not really strong, is it?

You've asked about brute-forcing, and there are different types. Trying every password length, character by character starting from `abcd...` is a sure way to *eventually* get the password, but it might take billions of years. But that's not the only type.

Dictionaries are used, common patterns are tried, known passwords are checked.

So, yes, if a 30-char password with dictionary words is used, and those words are randomly chosen, then that's a strong password.

`!@#$#%$^%$` will be guessed relatively quickly because that's a common keyboard pattern.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112202/discussion-on-answer-by-schroeder-does-brute-force-time-depend-on-the-length-of).

Answer (score -3):

It depends.

Suppose 10-character password uses 64 different characters. How many combinations are needed for brute-forcing? 64^10 = 2^60 ~= 10^18.

How many words are in the dictionary that you are going to use? Normally dictionary for such cases contains not every possible word in a language, but only some words, that are easier to remember and easier to spell correctly. Suppose such dictionary contains 2000 words. Suppose each password consists of 5 dictionary words.

How many combinations are needed for brute-forcing? 2000^5 ~= 3x10^16. Means such 30-character password will require **~30 times less** time to brute-force compared to 10-character password.

If you take other dictionary, let say containing 8000 words, the number of passwords to test for brute-forcing will be 8000^5 ~= 3x10^19. Now it is vise versa, 30-character password will require **~30 times more** time to brute-force compared to 10-character password.

As you see, it depends. A 30-character can be easier to brute-force as well as it can be harder to brute-force compared to 10-character password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112162/discussion-between-mentallurg-and-tim).